# Android Facebook SDK not getting Facebook profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, image, sdk, profile

I have integrated Facebook Login using facebook SDK in an android app.
I am trying to get fb profile picture from "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ profile.getId() + "/picture?type=large" to resample (taking bitmap of it) it for using in my app.

The issue is, the code works fine when I login from my personal fb account but fails when some body else tries it. I am stuck and need a clue to get this fixed.

Comment: You need to get loggined user profile picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreate()` of your activity, initialize facebook sdk before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` as `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`.

And do these inside your `onCreate()` method:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
String userID = accessToken.getUserId();
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large";
ImageView navProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.navProfilePic);
Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .resize(radius, radius)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(navProfile);
```

**Edit:** Add the other person as tester for your app on facebook. Then only, it will work. Otherwise get your application reviewed by facebook, and make it public so that anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you check the your application in facebook developer. if your application is not public then your application will not be work properly and is  accessible for only you.that wise is occurs issue.